# How do I convert a shockwave movie (swf) to another video format like mp4 / mpg?

Tags: mac, video, conversion

I have some swf's I want to convert to mov, avi, mp4 whatever for portability, etc. (on the mac)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah! I finally found something that works! [VidConvert](http://www.reggieashworth.com/vidconvert) by Reggie Ashworth, creator of the similarly elegant [AppDelete](http://www.reggieashworth.com/appdelete).

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about small(ish) files, the easiest thing you can do is just use an online service such as [Media Convert](http://media-convert.com/).

It supports SWF for import and has a huge variety of output formats.

Comment: trying this now...

Comment: I never got the email saying the conversion was complete :(

Answer (score 1):

Just use Visual Hub:

[image: visual hub screenshot]

Works a treat every time.  Unfortunately it's not available for download from the [creator](http://www.techspansion.com/)
anymore, but it can still be had via [alternate means](http://isohunt.com/torrent_details/114870185/Converting+WMV+Files+to+DVD?tab=summary).

The source files for the new open source version (filmredux) are [also available](http://transcoderredux.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/transcoderredux/FilmRedux/)

Comment: neither version worked for the .flv files I have (from youtube)